# Guardar Value de un Input Radio en una variable de Javascript

Tags: javascript, entrada, radiobutton

Este código corresponde al código JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Id = document.getElementsByName("rama");//ESTA ES LA FORMA QUE USO
    let activoFijo = $('input[name="activoFijo"]:checked').val();//ESTA LA ENCONTRE COMO RESPUESTA A OTRA PREGUNTA SIMILAR A ESTA
    $.post("../Sql/ArregloPersonas.php", {Id: Id
        }, function(){
            $("#personas-rama").html();
    });
});
</script>
```

La segunda parte del código contiene los input de tipo radio:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rama" value="1"> Manada
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rama" value="2"> Tropa
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rama" value="3"> Comunidad
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rama" value="4"> Clan
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quiero que cuando la persona seleccione un input radio su valor se almacene en una variable de JS y se muestre un alert que muestre el value seleccionado; y si se cambia el input radio también debe aparecer un alert con el nuevo value seleccionado.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda para este problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero, decirte que estás mezclando en tu Javascript sentencias realizadas con Javascript puro, con sentencias realizadas con Jquery. No es una buena practica y te puede llevar a hacerte un verdadero lío.

A continuación te pongo una función que te ayudará a conseguir el efecto deseado:

```js
var valor = '';

$("input[name='rama']" ).on('change', function () {
    valor = $(this).val();
    alert(valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rama" value="1"> Manada
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rama" value="2"> Tropa
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rama" value="3"> Comunidad
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rama" value="4"> Clan
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo que hago es agregar un evento **change** (este evento se dispara cuando el **input** cambia de valor) a todos los **input** con el nombre "rama". Luego guardo el valor en una variable que he inicializado fuera de la función y le hago un **alert**.